# Adjust the height of a textInput box as a user keeps typing

Tags: css, r, shiny

I try to adjust the height of the box of a textInput. However, I am not familiar with CSS. I found some similar problems in which they recommend to use the following CSS snippet:

```
max-height: 200px;
```

I would very much appreciate if someone could help me to implement this into Shiny assuming the following is the text input I try to alter.

```
textInput("remarks", label = h3("Text input"), value = "")
```

Comment: I am not really sure what it is you are trying to do. Do you have a code example like a jsfiddle? - if you are suing an `<input>` tag then it shouldnt go onto a second line you might be better using a `<textarea>` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A textarea may be what you are looking for:

```
   ui = fluidPage( h4('This is a text area:') 
                  ,tags$textarea(id = 'remarks', placeholder = 'Type here', rows = 3, value="" ) 
        ) 
  server = function(input, output) { } 
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want myltiple line input see @Ron Talbot answer

But if you realy want input with 200 px height you can do it in such way

```
library(shiny)

ui=shinyUI(fluidPage(
tags$head(tags$style("
                  #remarks  {  
   height: 200px;
                     }")),
textInput("remarks", label = h3("Text input"), value = "")
)

)

server=function(input,output){

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style>
        .text { height: 10px; }
    </style>
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".